# how to use php to exclude the last row in an array

Tags: php, foreach, count, advanced-custom-fields

I've been trying to read up on this in the manual, but basically I've got an `array` where I'm trying to reverse it and exclude the last item. So I got 14 items currently in my array and I'm getting it to reverse and it shows 14-2. My code got it to exclude the last item. So I guess it technically works, but I actually want it to output as 13-1. I tried using `array_pop` and `array_shift` but I didn't know how to integrate it with `array_reverse`.

```
function smile_gallery( $atts ) {
    if( have_rows('smile_gallery', 3045) ):

    $i = 1;

    $html_out = '';

    $html_out .= '<div class="smile-container">';
        $html_out .= '<div class="fg-row row">';

            // vars
            $rows = get_field('smile_gallery', 3045);
            $count = count( get_field('smile_gallery', 3045) );

            $html_out .= '<div class="col-md-8">'; // col-md-offset-1
                $html_out .= '<div class="smile-thumbs">';

                foreach( array_reverse($rows) as $row) :

                // vars
                $week = "smile_week";
                $img = "smile_img";
                $caption = "smile_caption";

                // Do stuff with each post here
                if( $i < $count) :

                    $html_out .= '<div class="smile-thumb-container">';
                        $html_out .= '><h6>Week ' . $row["smile_week"] . '</h6></a>'; // smile thumb week  
                    $html_out .= '</div>'; // smile thumb container
                endif;

                $i++;

                endforeach;

                $html_out .= '</div>';
            $html_out .= '</div>';
        $html_out .= '</div>';
    $html_out .= '</div>'; // smile container

    endif;

    return $html_out;
}
add_shortcode( 'show_smiles', 'smile_gallery' );
```

Comment: Move array_reverse out of the foreach and do your modifications before.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if I take it out, the `foreach` doesn't reverse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm reading your question as the following, correct me if I'm wrong.

> I've got an array where I'm trying to reverse it and exclude the first and last items.

To do that as you know you're want to use [array_pop()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) and [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php).

```
<?php
//
$rows = get_field('smile_gallery', 3045);
$count = count($rows);

array_pop($rows);
array_shift($rows);

foreach (array_reverse($rows) as $row):
...
```

If you want to reverse first and then do your operations, *which is not required if your removing items from both ends*. Take out `array_reverse` from the foreach and then do your manipulations.

```
<?php
// vars
$rows = get_field('smile_gallery', 3045);
$count = count($rows);

$rows = array_reverse($rows);

array_pop($rows);
array_shift($rows);

foreach ($rows as $row):
...
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: THAT'S IT! Jesus I've been trying so many things out, mainly with trying to mess with the count. I didn't need `array_shift`, but the `array_pop` worked exactly as I wanted. Out of curiosity, if I did `array_reverse($rows, true)` that would make it so I'd have to `shift` instead then ya? Anyhoot, you edited your message as I was responding. Keeping it as `foreach (array_reverse($rows) as $row):` worked for me.

Comment: Sorry yeah, I wasn't thinking about the keys as your code is not using them. You could also use either just shift or pop depending on if you place the array_reverse between them. but; whatever works for you. Glad to help.